# Change url of webview based on click

Tags: android, webview

I'm fairly new to developing for android; this is my first app. I let Android Studio generate a standard navigation drawer app. Ideally I want to be able to click on an item in the navigation drawer and then a webview loads the clicked website. I made a webview in the `.xml` file with id `main_webview`. What should I change to the `onItemClick` method to change the url?

```
public void onNavigationDrawerItemSelected(int position) {
    // update the main content by replacing fragments
    FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
    fragmentManager.beginTransaction()
            .replace(R.id.container, PlaceholderFragment.newInstance(position + 1))
            .commit();
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
WebView webpage = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.main_webview);
String pageUrl = "http://any-url-you-want/";

...onItemClick(params...){
    webpage.loadUrl(pageUrl);
}
```

Comment: And where should I add the webview to? `activity_login.xml`, `fragment_login.xml` or `fragment_navigation_drawer.xml`? I added it to `fragment_login` but the app keeps on crashing...

Comment: Add it to whichever is the current view / fragment. Add it to activity_login.

Comment: I did just that, could you maybe take a look at the updated question?